# Android app design guidelines

Tags: android, grid, size, metrics

I have read the Android Developers documentation and more specifically this one: http://developer.android.com/design/style/metrics-grids.html

So now my size for design must be 360dp * hdpi - hdpi @ 360.00dp = 540.00px width and custom height (depends on scrollable or unscrollable content). Did I understand right or?

Comment: Size of what do you mean?

Comment: @VladislavJordanòv, you must follow the guide lines and build you design following them. The custom height must be adjusted using the draw9patch which comes with the Android SDK. Take a look http://developer.android.com/tools/help/draw9patch.html

Comment: I need to present deisng preview, not to code the app. The programmers will do their job.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot be sure in any size of device, or even proportions. Both phones and tablets are VERY different: http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html#range You cannot "hardcode" something in design.

Comment: I need one size to start with and then convert to small sizes. Like the HDPI XHDPI XXHDPI sizes.

Comment: I just need to present the design not to code it. The programmers will code it, so I need a size to make it.

Comment: HDPI XHDPI XXHDPI are NOT screen sizes. You have to read link posted in my answer to undesrtand terms correct.